# Google sheets - reading nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing JSON data into Google Sheets with script. But JSON data have array in array. First are "pledges", then "transactions".

```
{"pledges":[{"pledgeId":1225981,"organizationId":358,"projectId":1170,"promotionId":null,"paymentMethod":"funds_transfer","isRecurrent":false,"pledgedAmount":{"cents":40000,"currency":"CZK"},"pledgedAt":"2017-09-06T20:58:19+02:00","donor":{"firstName":"XXXXXX","lastName":"XXXXXX","email":"XXXXXX","address":{"street":"XXXXXX","city":"XXXXXX","postCode":"XXXXXX"},"phone":"XXXXXX"},"wantDonationCertificate":false,"customFields":{"obraz_kalenadar":false},"transactions":[{"transactionId":1252314,"state":"sent_to_organization","sentAmount":{"cents":40000,"currency":"CZK"},"receivedAt":"2017-09-07T00:00:00+02:00","receivedAmount":{"cents":40000,"currency":"CZK"},"outgoingAmount":{"cents":39200,"currency":"CZK"},"outgoingVs":"XXXXXX","outgoingBankAccount":"XXXXXX"}]}
```

I have started with different script and rewritten it for my needs. I am able to retrieve all JSON data except transactions - those fields return "undefined".  I am pretty sure, that problem is with this: **pledges[i]["transactions"]**["transactionId"], but I am not able to figure out, how can I go deeper and reach those data correctly.

```
function darujmeJSON() {

  // URL pro Darujme API
  var root = 'https://www.darujme.cz/api/v1/organization/358/pledges-by-filter?apiId=XXXXXX&apiSecret=XXXXXX&fromPledgedDate=';

  // Set date X months back
  var mesic = 4; //how many months
  var now = new Date();
  now.setMonth(now.getMonth()-mesic);
  var endpoint = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'CET', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  // parameters for url fetch
  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  };

  try {
    // call the Darujme API
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root+endpoint, params);
    var data = response.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    // get pledges data
    var pledges = json['pledges'];

    // blank array to hold the pledges data for Sheet
    var pledgesData = [];

    // Add the pledges  data to the array
    for (var i = 0; i < pledges.length; i++) {

      // put the pledges data into a double array for Google Sheets
      if (pledges[i]["pledgeId"] != 0) {
        pledgesData.push([
pledges[i]["pledgeId"],
pledges[i]["organizationId"],
pledges[i]["projectId"],
pledges[i]["promotionId"],
pledges[i]["paymentMethod"],
pledges[i]["isRecurrent"],
pledges[i]["pledgedAmount"]["cents"],
pledges[i]["pledgedAmount"]["currency"],
pledges[i]["pledgedAt"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["email"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["firstName"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["lastName"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["phone"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["address"]["street"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["address"]["city"],
pledges[i]["donor"]["address"]["postCode"],
pledges[i]["wantDonationCertificate"],
pledges[i]["customFields"]["obraz_kalenadar"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["transactionId"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["state"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["sentAmount"]["cents"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["sentAmount"]["currency"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["receivedAt"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["receivedAmount"]["cents"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["receivedAmount"]["currency"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["outgoingAmount"]["cents"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["outgoingAmount"]["currency"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["outgoingVs"],
pledges[i]["transactions"]["outgoingBankAccount"]
]);
             }        
      }

    // Log the campaignData array
    Logger.log(pledgesData);

    // select the campaign output sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pledges');

    // calculate the number of rows and columns needed
    var numRows = pledgesData.length;
    var numCols = pledgesData[0].length;

    // output the numbers to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(pledgesData);    
  }
  catch (error) {
    // deal with any errors
    Logger.log(error);
  };

}
```

I am no coder, so I will be thankful for any ideas :-)

Comment: transactions is another array so you need something like `pledges[i]["transactions"][j]["transactionId"]`

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you! :-)